# Logging flask console messages to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to configure my flask logger so that log messages are printed to the console as well as a file. I have it partially working, but some of the flask messages are not being added to the file.

Here is a simplified version of my rest server.

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/siesta/<string:version>/test_steps", methods=["GET"])
def get_all_test_steps(version):
    if version == API_VERSION_1:
        app.logger.debug("DEBUG LOG MSG")
        return jsonify({"test_steps": test_step_manager.get_all_test_steps_json()})
    else:
        abort(404, "Invalid API version.")


def configure_logger():
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("RestServer.log")
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.addHandler(console_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = {"debug": True,
            "use_reloader": False,
            "host": "0.0.0.0"}
    configure_logger()
    app.run(**args)
```

When I access the route /siesta/v1/test_steps I see the following output in the console.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in RestServer [C:/Users/jhall/PycharmProjects/SQA_ROBOT_AUTOMATION/ExtremeAutomation/Library/Utils/Siesta/RestServer.py:366]:
DEBUG LOG MSG
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG LOG MSG
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2018 10:17:22] "GET /siesta/v1/test_steps HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The duplicate message is a bit annoying, but I can live with that.

However, in the file the only thing printed is this.

```
DEBUG LOG MSG
```

Is there a way to get the rest of the information into the log file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's likely because you got some imports that are not using the same logger root. In other words, you got a logger reference that you configure and use, and there's another one being used by other parts of your app. You should either configure the logger before the imports, or monkey patch the logger within those imports so they use your configured logger.

Comment: A) I believe the message is showing up twice because Flask is adding a formatter & a stream handler by default, so adding the console_handler again is why it is showing up twice B) the other information showing up in the console is due to Flask's default log formatter... so you need to set the formatter for your file_handler similar to what is described here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/

Comment: if you want to use the exact same formatter: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/4309c7c6ea51e5797604c43ba858e5ebe1fb1674/flask/logging.py#L55